# Reactive form reset, preserve state or not- Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

When you build a reactive form like:

```
this.addForm = this._fb.group({
  name: ['test'],
  age: ['', Validators.required],
  percentage: ['50', [Validators.required,Validators.max(100)] ] });
```

After reseting the form doest it preserve initial state; meaning values, validations or not? (All or any of them..)

Comment: No,  it will hard reset kind of form with no initial values  but with validatoion as per my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, so without any initial value reset works like first build state ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your validators will be fine. This merely "resets" the values.

If you were to reassign a value to this.addForm then you would of course lose them.

Comment: Thanks for quick-right answer!, so if I need the values I should setValue() method or setValidators() for new validation... in which condition should I use updateValueAndValidity() after?

Comment: If you are using setValidators(), you need to call updateValueAndValidity inorder to make validation take efforts updating the DOM

Answer (score 0):

*reset* will set the state of form group and sub controls to **pristine** and **untouched**, and the value to **null**. if you want to reset and set the value you can try this way

```
this.addForm.reset({name : 'test' , percentage : '50' }); // this reset and set value
```

if you form complex you can try this way

```
this.addForm = this._fb.group({
  name: ['test'],
  age: ['', Validators.required],
  percentage: ['50', [Validators.required,Validators.max(100)] ] });

this.initValue = this.addForm.value;
```

on reset

```
this.addForm.reset(this.initValue);
```